# Color-coded 50 Ohm BNCs

Tags: cables, colour

I would like to use some color coding in our experimental rig (microscope). All BNC cables so far are black 50 Ohm, and I'd like to use some yellow, red or any other very-not-black colors. I can't find these cables.

Are there are any special search keywords, apart from "Red 50 Ohm BNC", that I might use? Price at this point is not a real issue, if most BNCs are connected to BNC patch panel, they can be all black. But I'd like to highlight any non-BNC-patch-panel connected cables (temporary cables) so that they can be replaced later.

Comment: You can buy coloured heat-shrink sleeving, and mark the ends of your black cables.

Comment: Or colored electrical tape

Comment: Spray paint works wonders. Not on the connectors of course.

Comment: @Passerby i was thinking about spray paint, but as I remember, it makes stuff sticky.

Comment: I use heatshrink for marking stuff because it doesn't rub off like paint, or get sticky and peel off like tape.

Comment: @user44635 Great advice, I will try it out. Especially heat-shrinking sleeve, since I can make it any length along cable. Idea is to make this "temporary" cables particularly ugly/bright

Comment: Google  "Colored coaxial cable" and then click on "More images for colored coaxial cable"

Comment: Huber Suhner has various colour boots for their cable crimp connectors, look them up and find a local distributor to make up some cables for you.

Comment: @EMFields Thank you. It seems like on the market there are a lot of various colored coax cables but only few are terminated with 50 Ohm BNC, which is cheap enough for orders of 10-20 pcs.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the "jacket color". You can filter on color at many online stores, for example: [Brown Coax cable listed at Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1101=11&FV=fff40019%2Cfff8017b%2C11340002%2C11340003%2C11340004%2C11340005%2C11340006%2C11340008%2C1134000a%2C1134000b%2C11340010%2C11340011%2C1134001c%2C11340022%2C11340029%2C1134002c%2C1134002d&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25).

Colored patch cables are not common, so buy a reel and add the connectors yourself.

However, it is probably an expensive way of solving the problem, which could possibly be resolved with [silicon cable markers](http://www.sei-id.co.uk/cable-markers/silicone-cable-markers/fm-kitboxes) or other methods suggested in the comments.

Comment: It does turn out to be hard thing to find. I compare it to ethernet cables or power C13 cables, which can be virtually any color. I was hoping to go with whole-cable marking, not just terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few - just keep looking: -

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[**Here's**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GNJ8N8S) a link to the last one.

[image]

Coloured RG58 cable: -

[image]
[image]
[image]

From [**here**](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/pvc-red-coaxial-cable-rg58.html)

Comment: Its not exactly what OP asked for, but in my opinion a great solution.

Comment: @MarkCh oops forgot to add colored cable pictures.

Comment: These all come close to solving the underlying issue: labeling outstanding BNC cables. RG58 in colored jacket seems like the best, but it requires manual termination which sucks

Comment: @aaaaaa just do some more hunting on google - this took me about 5 or 10 minutes. Half an hour might turn-up some terminated cables in various colours.

Comment: @Andyaka yeah, I've spend some time before posting here. Thank you. I was actually seriously thinking about using RJ45-BNC breakout and colored Cat5 cables :)